# react/tolgee - translate function return output in screen but in console it is coming as function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, globalization, tolgee

Using the Tolgee library in React for switching between two languages in application

This is what I'm trying,

```
import { useTranslate } from '@tolgee/react';
const { t: translate } = useTranslate();

setMenu(
  apples.map((item: any) => {
    item.name = translate(item.key, { ns: item.ns });
    return item;
  })
);
```

In console I'm getting the value of item.name as translate(key | ns)
And in screen I'm getting the output value in single word as string, So I want to get the same output in console as what I'm getting in screen after DOM manipulation